# Custom WooCommerce 2.6 Loop

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm new to wooCommerce and I want to be able to display a single featured product from a category with different HTML markup than is used in the featured products shortcode like so:

`[featured_products per_page="1" columns="1"]`

I want to be able to do something like follows:

```
<div class="pure-g">
    <div class="pure-u-2-3">
        <h1>Product Name</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="pure-u-1-1 pure-u-md-2-3">
        <p>Product Description</p>
        <div>Link to single product page</div>
        <hr/>
    </div>
    <div class="pure-u-1-3">
        <img of product/>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm not sure how to use a WP query and loop to achieve this or if that's even possible.

I would appreciate any suggestions :)

Comment: whats an issue here??

Comment: Are you tried php???

Comment: I'm not sure how to use a query loop to get the information and display it how I want @VasimVanzara.

Comment: You can find if you google things

Comment: I haven't been able to find anything that works @VasimVanzara. Is there any chance you could link something that works? That would be most appreciated!